# Последовательность разработки схемы БД и мапинга классов

Tags: база-данных, spring, hibernate, orm, jpa

Как правильней? При работе с orm и бд(изначально база отсутствует) сначала создают схему базы и потом её мапят на классы или наоборот : мапят классы и автоматически генерируют базу из этих классов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кому как нравится, вокруг этого вопроса есть свои холивары. Моё мнение такое: лучше строить структуру БД, используя какую-либо из систем миграций (`Flyway`, `Liquibase`), и по ней уже создавать классы. Плюсы:

- Автогенерация БД требует сверки её состояния при каждом старте приложения, это может занимать много времени;
- Автогенерация не заменит систему миграции. Например, если требуется в очередном обновлении ПО изменить данные, а не структуру. А как описать в классах процедуры и триггеры? А раз система миграции нужна в любом случае, то зачем смешивать её с автогенерацией - это будет неясное разделение обязанностей;
- Полноценное описание структуры БД в классах (со всеми индексами, ограничениями, именами констрейнтов и пр.) занимает много места. Эти сведения нужны лишь один раз - непосредственно в момент внесения изменений в БД, но вам придётся оставить их в классах навсегда. Они будут мешать каждый раз, при работе с классом. А скрипты миграции хранятся отдельно, никому не мешая;
- Если приложение работает с СУБД, следует уделять достаточное внимание построению оптимальной её структуре. Если создавать сначала классы, то внимание смещается в сторону логики.

У автогенерации лишь один плюс:

- Меньше трудозатрат. Эта экономия чрезвычайно незначительна. Более того, если это реальный долгоживущий проект, то время, сэкономленное на старте, в будущем может обернуться потерями.